# ngfor is displaying only the first row. It is not printing the entire rows

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive, ionic3, ionic4

**Template**

```
<div>
  <ion-list *ngFor="let log of logList|orderBy: order; let i=index">
    <ion-item>
      <p>Log entries: <b>{{log[i].sub}}</b></p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</div>
```

here it is printing the first row only in screen. How should i go about this.

Comment: add the `orderBy` pipe code...

Comment: please print logList data here

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
<div>
  <ion-list *ngFor="let log of logList; let i=index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
    <ion-item>
      <p>Log entries: <b>{{log.sub}}</b></p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</div>
```

And in .ts

```
 trackByIndex(index: number) {
    return index;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's practical to use pipe for sorting while using ngFor. Instead sort it on page.ts file. For example:

```
 const logList=[
  {'id':'1','sub':'A'},
  {'id':'3','sub':'C'},
  {'id':'4','sub':'D'},
  {'id':'2','sub':'B'},
];

logList.sort((a,b)=> a.id-b.id);
```

Then, in page.html,

```
<div>
  <ion-list *ngFor="let log of logList">
    <ion-item>
      <p>Log entries: <b>{{log.sub}}</b></p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</div>
```